# How to update multiple Numpy arrays in a loop

Tags: python, arrays, loops, numpy, updates

I would like to update (prepend each one with additional elements) many numpy arrays in a loop, without having to repeat the code for each one.

I tried creating a list of all the arrays and looping through the items in that list and updating each one, but that doesn't change the original array.

```
import numpy as np
arr01 = [1,2,3]
arr02 = [4,5,6]
arr99 = [7,8,9]
print('initial arr01', arr01)
arraylist = [arr01, arr02, arr99]
for array in arraylist:
    array = np.concatenate((np.zeros(3, dtype=int), array))
    print('array being modified inside the loop', array)
print('final arr01', arr01)
```

In the sample code, I expected arr01, arr02, arr03 to all be modified with the prepended zeros.

Comment: `np.concatenate` returns a new array, and `array` is just reassigned to that array. The contents (i.e. the ndarrays in `arraylist`) are not modified. You could always do it by index--change the `for` loop to `for i in range(len(arraylist)):` and change `array` to `arraylist[i]`.

Comment: @PyNoob this would not work, because to look at the results, he uses the `arr01` variable again, which is unaffected by any `arraylist[i]` changes

Comment: @Saritus That's true, but this could be averted by printing `arraylist[0]`. If `ndarray` methods are desired, I don't know how else I would do it.

Comment: @PyNoob Maybe something like `arr01, arr02, arr99 = arraylist` after the iteration, so all changes inside `arraylist` are copied back to the original variables

Comment: You can't do this in a Python loop.   You have to use `arr02 = np.concatenate((np.zeros(3, int), arr02))`  for each named array.  Once you start down the 'arr01, arr02,...' route, you are stuck with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`array = np.concatenate((np.zeros(3, dtype=int), array))` does not change the current array but creates a new one and stores it inside the variable `array`. So for the solution you have to change the values of the array itself, which can be done with `array[:]`.

That means the only change you would have to make is replacing this one line

```
array[:] = np.concatenate((np.zeros(3, dtype=int), array))
```

So your correct solution would be

```
import numpy as np
arr01 = [1,2,3]
arr02 = [4,5,6]
arr99 = [7,8,9]
print('initial arr01', arr01)
arraylist = [arr01, arr02, arr99]
for array in arraylist:
    array[:] = np.concatenate((np.zeros(3, dtype=int), array))
    print('array being modified inside the loop', array)
print('final arr01', arr01)
```

Comment: OP's version made `array` a `numpy.ndarray` object, but `array[:]` keeps it as a `list` object, which may be an unintended side effect and something for others to keep in mind.

Comment: Outstanding answer. Such a small change fixed the problem completely!

Comment: Quick update... I realized when I feed numpy arrays in, instead of lists, then I had to adopt the other solution proposed jointly by PyNoob and Saritus, as follows:
    arraylist = [arr01, arr02, arr99]
    for i in range(len(arraylist)):
        arraylist[i] = np.concatenate((np.zeros(3, dtype=int), arraylist[i]))
        print('array being modified inside the loop', arraylist[i])
    arr01, arr02, arr99 = arraylist